# Regular Expression in JS: \\. does not match \n

Tags: javascript, regex

I am getting a string containing newlines (/n), tabs (/t) and lowercase letters [a-z]. It is possible to do that by matching `/\n|\t/`. AFAIK the dot represents the wildcard.

Therefore I was wondering, why `/\n|\t/` doesn't match the same things as `/\\./`

```
var text = 'test1 \ntest2';

text.split(/\n/)     //['test1', 'test2']
text.split(/\./)     //['test1 \ntest2']
text.split(/\\./)    //['test1 \ntest2']
```

Shouldn't the `\\.` match the `\n` (newline)?

Comment: Why should it not return null? `\n` is a single character not a \ followed by `n`

Comment: `/\\./` matches a backslash followed by a non-newline character. `/\./` matches a literal `.`.

Comment: @Moezalez Why should it? Your input string doesn't contain a backslash.

Comment: @Moezalez In that case both your string and your regex contain a single character each (a newline). I don't understand where your question is coming from.

Comment: @Moezalez You don't seem to understand that `\n` is JavaScript syntax that represents a single character. It's not stored as backslash-n at runtime. You could write the same character as `\x0a` or `\u000a`.

Comment: In future, please do not edit your question after attracting answers, in a way that invalidates those answers. Instead, ask a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me try and answer all the points:

> AFAIK the dot represents the wildcard.

No, in regex, we do not use the term "wildcard". It is a [*special regex (meta)character*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special). A dot in JavaScript regex matches any character but a newline.

> I was wondering, why `/\n|\t/` doesn't match the same things as `/\\./`

Because `/\n|\t/` matches 1 symbol, either a newline or tab, while the regex `/\\./` matches a literal `\` and a character other than a newline.

The `\n` and `\t` are *escape sequences*. That means that the `\` is not a literal backaslash that, together with the following symbol forms a code unit, a string that cannot be written otherwise. Indeed, how can we write a line break on the paper with a pen? No way!

See more about [JavaScript character escape sequences here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes).

Now,

> `text.split(/\n/)     //['test1', 'test2']`

True, your input string contains a line break, thus, you get two elements in the resulting array

> `text.split(/\./)     //['test1 \ntest2']`

No match was found because `\.` matches a literal dot. A dot that is escaped (that has a literal `\` before it) in the regex stops being a special regex metacharacter, and just matches its literal representation. Your string has no dot, thus, no matches.

> `text.split(/\\./)    //['test1 \ntest2']`

Again, no match is found, as `/\\./` looks for a literal `\` followed by any character but a newline.

A hint: use your expressions at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com), it will tell you what your regex can match on the right.

Here, with regex, you have a literal notation (`/.../`). In literal notation, `\` is considered a literal, thus, you do not have to escape it twice. If you used a constructor notation (i.e. `RegExp(....)`), you would have to use double escaping. E.g.

```
var re = /\\./; // is equal to
var re = new RegExp("\\\\.");
```

See more about constructor and literal notations at [MDN `RegExp` help page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 0):

`\n` gets evaluated to a new line, so you're essentially matching against an empty string. If you do a quick `console.log('\n');` you can see the output of that.